# How to convert UTC timestamps to multiple local time zones in R Data Frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I have a data frame df and it has 2 columns ( utc timestamps & time zones) , and I want to create a column that shows local time basis local time zone . I tried few things as given below .

```
This is my dataframe 

df<-data.frame(utc_time_stamp=c("2019-04-28 18:35:26","2019-04-28 21:28:58","2019-04-28 18:59:01"),time_zone=c("Asia/Tokyo","Australia/Brisbane","Etc/GMT-12"))


#This is what I tried 

df$utc_time_stamp<-as.POSIXct(df$utc_time_stamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz='GMT')


df$new_local_time<-format(df$utc_time_stamp,tz=df$time_zone,usetz=TRUE)



#This is the error I get 

Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value
```

Comment: Note that a column cannot have datetimes in different time zones. "new_local_time" has to be strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with a) factors and b) passing vectors. So one solution is to set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` and create a function to `Vectorize` your inputs:

```
df <- data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$utc_time_stamp <- as.POSIXct(df$utc_time_stamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz='GMT')

tz_v <- Vectorize(function(x,y) {format(x, tz=y, usetz=TRUE)})

df$new_local_time <- tz_v(df$utc_time_stamp, df$time_zone)
df
```

Output:

```
>>>        utc_time_stamp          time_zone           new_local_time
>>> 1 2019-04-28 18:35:26         Asia/Tokyo  2019-04-29 03:35:26 JST
>>> 2 2019-04-28 21:28:58 Australia/Brisbane 2019-04-29 07:28:58 AEST
>>> 3 2019-04-28 18:59:01         Etc/GMT-12  2019-04-29 06:59:01 +12
```

Comment: If I want to do same thing in sparklyr , how this script would change ? TIA

Comment: if df is big file (5GB), then "df$new_local_time <- tz_v(df$utc_time_stamp, df$time_zone)" is taking hours , any suggestions to address the issue ?

Comment: Perhaps a tidyverse solution with ``dplyr``: ``df %>% group_by(time_zone) %>% mutate(new_local_time=format(utc_time_stamp, tz=time_zone, usetz=TRUE))``. Hard for me to say without a large ds to hand.

Comment: What is the equivalent of "tz_v <- Vectorize(function(x,y) {format(x, tz=y, usetz=TRUE)}) " ?  How do I achieve this in dyplyr ( how to achieve vectorize objective in dyplyr )?

Comment: You won't need to vectorise if you use dplyr. Just apply the code above directly to the df (after the second line in my solution above).

Comment: I tried above code , issue is that it is taking too long to execute the code ....4-5 hrs  !! Any workaround with that or any other approach u would suggest ?

Comment: You could try ``mapply`` instead of the ``dplyr`` approach above: ``df$new_local_time <- mapply(function(x,y) {format(x, tz=y, usetz=TRUE)}, df$utc_time_stamp, df$time_zone)``

Comment: when I use this code                                                                                                     
 df %>% group_by(time_zone) %>% mutate(new_local_time=format(utc_time_stamp, tz=time_zone, usetz=TRUE))  
 ...I get an error Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: invalid 'tz' value.

Comment: It works for my version of the df you posted. I noticed that you had time_zonne rather than time_zone in the original post. Could it be that?

Comment: It was a type ...problem persists even after making correction...Issue is calculation taking perennially  long time even for mapply........